# Use of SPListCollection.Add Method (String, String, String, String, Int32, String, SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions) in sharepoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, list

How to use of

```
SPListCollection.Add(String, String, String, String, Int32, String, SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions)`
```

method for creating SharePoint document library programmatically using asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

### Adding a document library that appears on the Quick Launch area

**Hard way** - using the [Add(String, String, String, String, Int32, String, String, SPFeatureDefinition, SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee580457.aspx) method overload

```
web.Lists.Add("Old documents",
  "This library stores old documents.",
  "old-docs",
  "00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101",
  101,
  "101",
  SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions.On);
```

- the `featureId` parameter (4th one) is a string that contains the ID of the feature that defines the list; you can find feature IDs of standard list definitions online ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543357.aspx), [here](https://www.thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2007/05/16/list-of-features-with-guids.aspx) or [here](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/create-custom-lists-in-caml-based-on-existing-list-templates/)) or in appropriate files in the 12 hive

**Easy way** - in 2 steps

```
Guid newListGuid = web.Lists.Add("Old documents",
  "This library stores old documents.",
  SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);

SPList newList = web.Lists[newListGuid];
newList.OnQuickLaunch = true;
newList.Update();
```

Comment: Thanx Marek.But can you please explain by example that how to use this add method with QuickLaunch Options? I don't know how to use this function with all parameters.

Comment: Thanx again.I don't know what i pass in Feature id parameter(4th parameter in add method) for document library?

Comment: No, I don't want to show/hide any link.But when i create any item "IT" into particular list say department, at that time i want to create document library "IT" dynamically.And i also want to display that library in quick launch.For that reason, i am using above add method but i don't know how to pass Feature id parameter(4th parameter in add method) in add function?